# How to navigate to one of the previous screens in stack and refresh content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a scenario where I need to navigate from Screen A to Screen B, then to Screen C, and finally, directly back to Screen A from Screen C while refreshing the content of Screen A. How can I navigate directly from Screen C to Screen A while refreshing the content of Screen A upon navigation? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does navigating to C pop the stack two times or add C on top of the stack?

Comment: no, A and B remain in the navigation stack when C is pushed

Comment: This task might be easier to accomplish using declarative navigation (as opposed to imperative navigation with push/pop). I recommend having a look at the documentation of the package `go_router` section `Go directly to a destination`: https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html

Answer (score 0):

Easier workaround is to await for the navigator to return to that page using an await. I have created a small demo for you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScreenA(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          await Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenB()));//await here
          refreshPage();
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(child: Text("Goto ScreenB")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void refreshPage() {
    print("page Refreshed");
    //write refresh code here
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScreenC()));
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(child: Text("Goto ScreenC")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenC extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenC({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
           Navigator.of(context)
            ..pop()
            ..pop();
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(child: Text("Goto ScreenA")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here Refresh Page in ScreenA class will be triggered when the user gets back to screenA from screenC.

Comment: asker doesnt pop